# Postgres: How to find rows in which a specific column has 'empty' values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find rows which have a empty values in a column after a CSV import.
The column is an `INTEGER` column, hence the

```sql
...
where col = ''
```

doesn't work for me.

Comment: Where col is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for *empty* values using

```
where col is null
```

If you want to select null as 0 (or any other default value) use coalesce

```
select coalesce(max(col), 0)
```